# Run .jar in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Hi I'm a noob when it comes to web app development but after following several tutorials and asking questions at stackoverflow I was able to build a web app. 
The tutorials I initially followed use Spring Boot and so I ended up with a .jar app. But when it was deployment time, I was told by my boss to use Tomcat because the same server will run PHP/Apache and Tomcat.

I followed this [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) on how to convert a jar to war. But I encountered several problems in my implementation.

For example, the webpages can find the css file in /src/main/webapp/resources/css when running the java app but the webpages can't find the file when I converted to war. I also get a null pointer exception in when using tomcat which I don't get running the .jar app.

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = application.context();
MyJDBCTransaction myJDBCTransaction = ctx.getBean(MyJDBCTransaction.class);

    return application.sources(MyApp.class);
}
```

When I analyze the log, the offending code is

```
MyJDBCTransaction myJDBCTransaction = ctx.getBean(MyJDBCTransaction.class);
```

Basically, everything is OK (including the JDBC transactions) using the jar created by Spring Boot but I get into trouble deploying the war file

Is there a way to just run the .jar app inside Tomcat?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You don't run jars in tomcat.  There's a million ways to create a WAR file, depending on your environment.  Are you using an IDE?  Do you use maven, gradle, ant, or anything like that?

Comment: Can you specify where do you get `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I modified the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) you will find some instructions on how to get the war file running.

The idea is that, when changing from a jar to a war replaces the need for a ***main*** method, but requires you to configure a different "signal" for the servlet container on how to launch the application. An you do that by extending a ***SpringBootServletInitializer***